# Not able toDebug app in device using android studio

Tags: android

I installed my app on device ,but it was not running ,it is throwing an error,but this is not the same with emulator,its running perfectly fine.I need to check what is the issue ,so i tried to debug connecting a USB but not getting the way.

Please tel me steps to debug the app in android studio.Went through all tutorials but not working out.I followed this http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html but found we should not set debuggable.

Comment: What error was it showing when you tried running it on the device?

Comment: Unfortunatly 'app' has stopped

Comment: Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration. This should be checked.

Comment: In that case look in the logcat console output to see exactly where the error occurs. ALT + 6 in Android studio

Comment: android studio is not able to see my device,how to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ,Install Particular Phone driver in PC along with Google USB driver.
This will allow you debug.